# Migrating domain from one cpanel account to another and DNS propagation

Tags: domains, dns, cpanel, migration

I have two accounts that I wish to migrate from an old cpanel server to a new cpanel server over the weekend.

Each of the accounts has a domain and those domains are not managed by me, they belong to two clients.

These domains are pointing to my old server (ns1.mydomain.tld and ns2.mydomain.tld).

If I migrate the accounts from this old server to a new server, am I able to setup dns records in the old server so that if requests come to the old server they redirect clients to the new server?

I want to be able to migrate the accounts without having to be synchronized with the clients for changing their DNS records. After the accounts are migrated to the new cpanel account, I would notify them to change the DNS records to ns3.mydomain.tld and ns4.mydomain.tld.

Is this feasible and am I looking at this the right way, or should I approach this problem differently?

Would this pose problems for email deliverability and site access for those domains?

EDIT:
Should I do this the other way around? Should I ask my clients to first change the DNS records of their domains, and until the accounts are migrated to the new server, have the new server redirect requests for those domains to the old server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create the account on the new server and do an initial transfer.  Then change the MX records to point at the new server.   Given propagation there *may* be a period where email goes to one server or the other for different people.

Then change the nameservers.  Once propagation is complete rsync the mail directories or re-import using cpanel assuming it doesn't overwrite existing data.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, that seems like a good approach.

Comment: I am using something like this for syncing: rsync -axuvr ~/ [user]@[new.server.tld]:~/ from within the old server user account

Answer (score 0):

"If I migrate the accounts from this old server to a new server, am I able to setup dns records in the old server so that if requests come to the old server they redirect clients to the new server?"

Your host can do that for you, from their back end, but yes, it is absolutely possible.  Our servers do it automatically, but they are all of our connected servers.  It may be a bit different when you are talking about 2 different hosting companies.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What do you mean by the host can do that? Can't this be done from within whm / cpanel? Where is this configuration made?